# concatenate the result of my request to the question that launches amazon lex

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have a REST GET API, from this API I get values ​​and those values ​​I want to concatenate to the questions that amazon lex launches, how can I achieve this?

[image: here is the image of the flow]

In the image I show with the red boxes where I want to concatenate the result of my request.

Thank you !!

Comment: Hmm, this sounds like 2 unrelated questions to me. If not, can you explain what you are trying to do and why you want to either create slots in Lambda or get the launch question in Lambda?

Comment: Hi Jay, I have already updated my question, thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can build your response message however you want in Lambda when you deliver your ElicitSlot response under `dialogAction > message > content`.

To concatenate a string with string-variables in both Node.js and Python, simply use `+` .

Here is an example:

```
responseMessage = "The available dates are: 1. " + dateA + " 2. " + dateB + "...";
slots = event.currentIntent.slots;

"dialogAction": {
    "type": "ElicitSlot",
    "intentName": "intent-name",
    "slots": slots,
    "slotToElicit" : "slot-name",
    "message": {
      "contentType": "PlainText",
      "content": responseMessage
    },
}
```